# Error:: ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found within AWS.config.credentials.refresh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to perform a dynamodb db operation and generate a report which worked fine but some times in production, am seeing the error - CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 using identity poolid. Hence I updated the code to refresh the token as below -

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.789.0.min.js"></script>

var GetWallboardx = () => {

    AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-2';
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0e8',
    });
    
    //refreshes credentials using AWS.CognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()
    AWS.config.credentials.refresh(error => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {;
        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
      }
    });
    
    docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        -- some db operation --
    })
    
    setTimeout(GetWallboardx,RefreshInterval)// run this every 5 seconds
}

GetWallboardx()
```

if I try to use this 'refresh approach' looks like am not able to access dynamo db as the error says - Error:: ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found. Can any one please help me. I did not get this exception when I did not use the 'refresh' earlier like this -

```
var docClient;

AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-2';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0e8',
});

docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of refresh() is promise method that means it is running asynchronize. You may need some knowledge of async promise on javascript. Another thing you should refer to this link how to work with credentials refresh()

[Users should call get / getPromise before using refresh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html#get-property)

See example below to solve your case :

```
var GetWallboardx = async () => {
     try {
         // whether the credentials object should call refresh()
         if (AWS.config.credentials.needRefresh()) {
              await refreshCredentials();
         }

         let data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
         // some db operation

         setTimeout(GetWallboardx(),5000) // run this every 5 seconds
     } catch(e) {
         // Error handler
     }
}

var refreshCredentials = async () => {
    await AWS.config.credentials.refreshPromise();
}

var getCredentials = async () => {
    try {
        AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-2';
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0e8',
        });
    
        // Should call this method to have ability using refresh()
        await AWS.config.credentials.getPromise();

        // once users get the credential identity, it is able to do refresh()
        console.log('getCredentials done: ',AWS.config.credentials.identityId)
        // await refreshCredentials()

        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
        
        GetWallboardx();
    } catch(e) {
        // Error handler
    }
}

getCredentials()
```

I not yet tried that code, but I think it should work as expected. Just let me know if you have a problem with.

Comment: you are right. I dont have much knowledge on promises in javascripts but I have to fix this code developed by somebody else :) I tried the sample code that you shared. I dont see the resource not found exception now. But nothing seems to work in the try block of getWallboardx function. No console.logs are printed. No report is generated. Could you please help me fix this. Please see my updated code here - https://jsfiddle.net/x3msq89v/

Comment: I dont understand what the goal from your dynamodb scan? Try the updated code below https://jsfiddle.net/1rwf3Las/

Comment: I added the updated code and still get the ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found. Screenshot of the error for your reference - https://imgur.com/gN3HTma and here is my updated code - https://jsfiddle.net/cz10qdef/

Comment: Within the try block, only the params can be seen in the console.log and after that the data console.log and the remaining are not seen

Comment: well, I think it's because of the very long refreshInterval set. Just noticed it was set to 5*60*1000, it equals to 5 minutes. I changed it 5*1000 for 5s and tested on my system, it works now https://jsfiddle.net/k40udfsq/

Comment: I still get the same error from my end even after reducing the refreshinterval. Anyhow, I have stopped working on thi approach as the requirement has been changed. This is no longer needed for me. I am grateful for your help and knowledge sharing